# C# MVC4 Html Action Call to custom routed ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have the following Controller

```
namespace ExampleProject.Areas.Plugins.Default.Admin.Controllers
{
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
}
```

I have the following custom route in my PluginsAreaRegistration.cs

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Plugins_Default_Admin",
    "Plugins/Default/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
       namespaces: new[]{
           "ExampleProject.Areas.Plugins.Default.Admin.Controllers"
       }
);
```

So when I call the url "/Plugins/Default/Admin/Home/Index", I will get to the ActionResult in the controller Above.

What I want achieve is to call the Index ActionResult using Html.Action in a different View

Example:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Home", new {area = "Plugins" })
```

I'm not sure how I can point the the specific home controller that I want? I have multiple HomeControllers in the Plugins Area, all with different routes.

Error I'm getting is "Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'."

Comment: You can use `@Html.RouteLink()` and pass RouteName as parameter to it. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @ramiramilu, I don't want to create a link. I want the content from the the Plugins/Default/Admin/Home/Index. I can achieve this with ajax, but I don't want to go ajax as I want the content to be there on page load.